# Trying to understand Objective C classes and methods

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode4.2

I am new to iPhone development and Objective C. I have decided I would do some tutorials on Objective C first to get the hang of the language, however there a few things I am unsure about and would be grateful if someone could explain them to me.

I have downloaded Xcode 4.2 from app store, so am using.

First question, can you only have one main class in objective C? I am going through the NewBoston tutorials at the moment, and he has many different tutorials, and I am used to Java programming, where I just create a new class for each tutorial. In Objective C however, when you create a new project, you get a file called main.m which seems to be default class which always executes. I am used to java, where when you just create one project, and can have as many classes as you want within it and can just choose which class you want to run. Can you not do something like this in Objective C? Or do I have to create a new project for each tutorial I do? As I don't want to keep just changing the main class, when I finish a tutorial I like to keep the file so I can go back and check on it if I ever forget anything.

And second quick question about the main method in Objective C. The main method is declared like this

```
int main(int argc, char *argV[]){
```

Why is the main method an int declaration? I am used to Java, where main method is void as main methods don't return anything. It seems odd to me that the main method for Objective C is an int. Just would be nice to understand.

Thanks in advance for any help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1) In Objective-C you have one `main` function that gets run at startup. Combined with the fact that the iOS runtime does some initialization, too, and get that information from the project info (e.g. startup Storyboard / NIB) you can only have one entry point per project. This somewhat stems from the fact that while Java maintains a lot of namespace info and has no predifined entry point per se, Objective-C does compile everything down to one file and looks for the one function called `main`. You could see this like a jar-file which has a predefined entry point set on its own; only you cannot change the name of the entry point.

2) The return type of main: For a long time, programs had return codes to indicate success (return code 0) or failure (return code greater than zero, mostly documented in man pages etc.). Actually you do have the same in Java, have a look at `System.exit(int exitcode)`, Java simply has some default-handling as in man cases return codes are not needed anymore (especially when writing GUI applications).

Comment: Thanks for answers both of you. Guess just means making more projects. Think I definitely prefer Java :P

Comment: @AdamM If you understand how to write good programs in obj-c, it will help to write better programs in Java.

Comment: Perhaps, at the moment, I just find it a bit confusing trying to get used it. The syntax seems quite difficult to get used to, but then only been using it for two days, just I need to use it for part of my job, so a lot to learn over next while.

Answer (score 1):

1. You should only have one `main.m` with a single `main` method per project.
2. `main` returns `int` as an exit status code that can be evaluated by the caller of the program. This is very common in C and derived languages. Returning `0` means "everything went ok". Other status codes usually mean that something went wrong.

Answer (score 1):

I agree with everything TriPhoenix wrote.

I have only one small commment.

Inside the `main` function (it is a *function* not a class *method*) on iOS you always call function UIApplicationMain which starts you application.

Since applications on iOS never exit, `UIApplicationMain` function never returns and thus your `main` function never returns. In iOS the return value has no meaning. It's there only for consistency.